# The boundedness of convolution operator.

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, convolution

I'm stuck in the following two questions
(All index sets below are natural numbers).

1. Assume that $a=(a_n)$ is a sequence of scalars in $\ell^p$ for some $p>1.$ Fix some $q>1$. If $a\ast b\in \ell^q$ for any $b\in \ell^q$,   must $a\in \ell^1$?.
2. Fix $1<p<2$ and assume that $a = (\frac{1}{n})$. Then does there exist $b\in \ell^p$ such that $a\ast b\notin \ell^p$? Or, is $T:\ell^p\rightarrow \ell^p$ defined by $T(b)= a\ast b$ a well-defined linear operator?

Any feedback or reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing $q$ here is supposed to be the conjugate of $p$, aka $\frac1p + \frac1q = 1$? Or is it any $q$? You should also edit the question with what you have tried.

Comment: No, $q$ is just an arbitrary number greater than 1.

Comment: I'm so sorry that I didn't write what I've tried. The thing is the work I've done didn't really help (I guess). For example, the first question seems to be related to the sharpness of Young's convolution inequality but the sharpness of Young's convolution inequality doesn't really help here (See Lieb and Loss). For the  second question, I tried some $(b_n)$ which is in $\ell^p$ but not in $\ell^q$ for any $q<p$ (for example $(\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{n})^{1/p}(ln\,n)^{2/p}})$), but $b\ast (1/n)$ is still in $\ell^p$.